# OpenLayers 3 Zoombox and Navigation

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I used Zoombox and Navigation with opanlayer 2 version and it's very easy.But I don't know how to use zoombox and navigation in openlayer 3 version.Please help me.For Sample [LINK](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/navtoolbar-alwaysZoom.html)

Answer (score 0):

In OL3, the `ol.Map` object comes with a collection of interactions, which include both what used to be the zoombox and navigation back in OpenLayers 2.  The only difference is that they are no longer `Controls`.

A control in OL3 as a UI component, like a button, a div, etc.  It can content one or more interaction.  An interaction has no UI component, but the user interacts with it with the mouse, keyboard, etc.

If you don't define the interactions you want with your map, then the default ones are used.  See which ones in the documentation here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#defaults

Comment: can you send me example for this?

Comment: Sure.  See this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/9v6fd6as/1/.  In it, we disable the default dragpan interaction, then defines our own with the kinetic turned off.  That's a way to disable the 'default' interactions and define your own.  For controls, see this other example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/custom-controls.html.  You'll see that it includes custom controls, which have UI components on the map.  HTH.